# METHOD FOR THE 3D RECONSTRUCTION OF A SCENE US20180063506 - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant

[US 20180063506](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20180063506A1) This application seeks to patent a method which has been previously published in a PhD thesis in: https://www.theses.fr/2014PA066593
[pre-grant][prior-art-request]

Comment: Here is a link to the actual thesis in both English and France. https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01142048/document

Answer (score 1):

João Carneiro (of the mentioned thesis) along with Ryad Benosman (his thesis Guide) and Sio-Hoï Ieng (one of the thesis reviewers) filed WO2013083848A1 mentioned in the thesis page20 (pdf en page no. 29). It enetered National Phase and was granted in [these countries](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2013083848&recNum=&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=1000&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=).

Ryad Benosman and Sio-Hoï Ieng are co-inventors besides Shi BERTRAM for application of this question. Specification admits the invention to be improvement of prevailing art.

> Para 0011] The present invention aims to improve the situation. and
>   [0012] To this end, the present invention proposes a method, especially
>   suited to asynchronous sensors to reconstruct scenes observed in 3D.

Of course there are new equations and new technical terms added as compared to first mentioned application. Claims are also very professionally drafted.

> Interestingly, the [very patent application](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2013083848&recNum=&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=1000&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=) and the thesis
>   mentioned in question, with which both Ryad Benosman and Sio-Hoï Ieng
>   are associated with, do not find mention in their [application](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20180063506A1).